# A Rare Transition

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I am Austerity.
>
> I am Irrelevance.
>
> I am Curation in a Snowstorm.
>
> I am Mnemonic.
>
> I am the Schism.
>
> I am Curiosities in the Allusive.
>
> I am Corruption.
>
> I am Rebirth.
>
> I am Ferocious Chaos.

**What am I?**

Comment: **I am Groot.**

Comment: You're Mnemonic too?  What are the odds?

Comment: A mistake was edited, I can't believe missed it before posting but it's too late now lol. The answer is still the same, just the little 'easter-eggs' I added wouldn't have worked without the change.

Comment: I read @Menmonic 's comment as a response to Rand al'Thor's instead of to the OP. It still works....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you

> A *Metal* 
>
>
>   The first letters of each Capiltalized word after 'I am' word is a Chemical symbol of metal, or for the final clue carbon, which is found in alloys which this puzzle also extends to.

I am Austerity.

> *Au = Gold*

Irrelevance.

> *Ir = Iridium*

Curation in a Snowstorm.

> *Cu = Copper* , *Sn = Tin*
>
>  Then combining Cu and Sn give the alloy *[Bronze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bronze)*

Mnemonic

> *Mn = Manganese*

the Schism

> *Th = Thorium*, *Sc = Scandium*

Curiosities in the Allusive

> *Cu = Copper*, *Al = Aluminium*
>
>  Then combining Cu and Al give the alloy *[Aluminium bronze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_bronze)*

Corruption

> *Co = Cobalt*

Rebirth

> *Re = Rhenium*

Ferocious Chaos

> *Fe = Iron*,  *C = Carbon* possibly  giving Iron + Carbon = *Steel*

The title 'A Rare Transition'

> Relates to the Rare Earth and Transition metals

Comment: It didn't even dawn on me that everything related to them, I was focusing on metals but yes you are mostly correct! I also noticed a huge mistake I made just now, might need to switch something out lol.

Comment: Oh, I see, yes I might add that in to the answer if Ok. Thanks for this!

Comment: Some of the answers aren't quite right, but are very close (and I've changed one part). The lines with two 'words' also form a new 'answer'.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the lines with double capitalized words - not Certain :)

Comment: Hint: **Combine**. I hope that helps

Comment: Just like you did Ferocious Chaos!

Comment: The combination two word clues were *Nice* !!!

Comment: Thanks, at least the clues aren't atrocious like my last riddle lol.